# vCenter Server Appliance 6.0 : 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: vmware, http-status-code-503, vcenter, appliance

`503 Service Unavailable (Failed to connect to endpoint:` `[N7Vmacore4Http16LocalServiceSpecE:0x7fc8bad2f810] _serverNamespace = /vsphere-client _isRedirect = false _port = 9090)`

This is the error i'm constantly getting when trying to connect to the vCenter Server Web Client.

#### Details :

- I'v installed the **vCS Appliance 6.0** on an **ESXi 6.0** host. It's running on top of it along other VMs.
- I can access the vCS appliance thourght an **SSH** client, but every attempt to access the web client ends with the error above.
- I'v found that causes for this error are: the server being overloaded or under maintenance. However, I'm the **only one** to have access to this platform.

Any ideas ?

#### EDIT: Solved

I had a copy of the current vCenter appliance stored on the same ESXi. This created an IP conflict. I changed the IP address of the backup before its creation and the problem was solved

Comment: A few troubleshooting notes, since you have SSH access you can (1) check the status of the Web Client "service vsphere-client status", you can run it manually if it's not running for some reason (2) you can check the detailed Web Client logs at /var/log/vmware/vsphere-client/, they might contain more info about the issue

Comment: Thankx @erkfel. I'v figured the problem a while ago:
I made a backup of the current vCenter appliance and stored it on the ESXi 6.0 without changing it's IP address. This created an access conflict.
All I had to do is to change the IP address of the backup during its creation and Hop it's solved

Comment: Would you mind putting the information on how you solved this into an "Answer" then marking it as such? That would be very helpful for the StackOverflow site :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

The problem was that I made a backup of the current vCenter appliance and stored it on the ESXi 6.0 without changing it's IP address. This created an access conflict. All I had to do is to change the IP address of the backup during its creation and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that 503 error, but my case was a little different:

I changed the IP address of my VCSA 6.0 Update 2 plus its default gateway via the GUI (https://x.x.x.x:5480).

I was able to ping it and ssh into it afterwards, but I was not able to login using either the old (thick) client or the web client. Both were giving me the 503 Server error.

I tried rebooting, but nothing.

After the reboot, I SSHd into it and was able to see that the web client service was not running. The vpxd service was running though. So I started it:

```
vcsa6:~ # service vsphere-client status
VMware vSphere Web Client is not running.

vcsa6:~ # service vmware-vpxd  status
vmware-vpxd is running

vcsa6:~ # service vsphere-client start
Last login: Sat Dec 10 23:40:00 UTC 2016 on console
Starting VMware vSphere Web Client...
Waiting for VMware vSphere Web Client......
running: PID:22433

vcsa6:~ # service vsphere-client status
VMware vSphere Web Client is running: PID:22433, Wrapper:STARTED, Java:STARTED
```

I was still getting the 503.

I found then this [link](http://www.settlersoman.com/how-to-change-vcenter-appliance-vcsa-6-x-ip-address/), which basically told me to edit the /etc/hosts file of the VCSA and voila: the VCSA FQDN entry in there was still pointing to the old IP address. I changed it and rebooted and now both clients, web and thick, work as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had 503 error issues on my lab/test vCenter 6.0 Update 1. I installed the integrated VCSA on a host that has limited memory, so I dropped the default 8G RAM and multiple CPU to 1 CPU and 4G. I would not go below those and use the default values if you can as webclient 503 errors occur and inventory service connection issues arise without the required RAM. I experienced no issues on the fat client.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with:

```
/etc/init.d/vpxa restart
```

Then I had some problems with hostd.

```
/etc/init.d/hostd restart
```

It worked great after.

ESXi 6.5 here.

Answer (score -1):

check to see if the vmware-vpxd is not stopped. If it is, start it.

-Putty into vcenter (VCSA)-

Comment: Please do elaborate your answer too.